# What factors determine the suction of an exhaust fan?

Tags: pressure, electronics, fan

What factors determine the suction of an electric exhaust fan used in kitchens?

I thought about fan-speed, voltage, air-pressure, difference in air pressure, circulation.

Comment: What do you mean by "the suction?" Are you asking about the amount of air it moves per unit time? Are you asking about the pressure difference between the inlet and the outlet? Are you asking about the volume of space near the inlet from which cooking smoke will be unable to escape? Are you asking about something else?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

A good guide to fan effectiveness in general is fan *power* which is the current draw times the voltage when running at the fan's *rated speed*.

The most useful measure is the *CFM rating* which is cubic feet per minute, but not all fans advertise this.

You will find that the annoying noise produced by a running fan is directly related to its power rating. The residential fan industry (for kitchen exhausts and bathroom ventilation) use an oddball noise unit called the *sone*. The best fans have the highest CFM and the lowest sone output.

Since fan noise is produced by the fan blades, artful design of the blades is necessary to minimize noise. In large free-standing/oscillating fans for room cooling, the quietest fans have blades with significant *overlap*, where the trailing edge of one blade obscures the leading edge of the next blade. This overlap blocks the noise radiated by the leading edge of the ban blade.